# bash script with mysql insert into - do other on duplicate entry

Tags: bash, mysql, duplicate

I have a mysql table with some unique constraints.
I have a script that asks some questions, and then inserts the answers into the mysql table.

I don't know how to tell the script to do something else if a duplicate entry exists.

I'd like to give the option to remove the entry and add the new, or return to the start begin the script again.

Hope that makes sense.

Preston

Comment: This is more a programming question that I recommend you to post on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest running a query to see if the record exists first and then you can have some bash logic to decide what to do based on the result of the query. Maybe something like this...

```
CHECK_ROW_EXISTS=$(mysql -u dbuser -p --batch -N -e "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbname.dbtable WHERE id = ${ID_TO_CHECK}")
```

Using `--batch` and `-N` will remove the formatting so that we can assign the result to a bash variable and then decide what to do from there.

The other option is to check the exit status code of the mysql insert and, if it fails, decide what to do from there.

Further reading: [get the sql query result with out table format | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711598/get-the-sql-query-result-with-out-table-format)

Comment: :)  Good call.  I will definitely try that.  Thanks